# connecting php with postgresql

Tags: php

I am a newcomer and have just started building a website.. I wrote the following code but its not working.it is not connecting to the database..If not this is there any other way to connect dreamweaver to postgresql ...please help..thnx in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
</head>
<body>
<div class="span6">
  <table class="table table-striped">
     <thead>  
          <tr>  
            <th>Scheme-ID</th>  
            <th>Scheme Name</th>  
            <th>Scheme Type</th>  

          </tr>  
        </thead>
        <tbody>
<?PHP


        $conn = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=egram user=postgres password=password") or die("unable to connect to database");
        if ($conn) 
        {   

        echo ("Connection attempt succeeded.");   

        }
         else {   

        echo ("Connection attempt failed.");   

        } 

    $sql = "SELECT scheme_id,scheme_name,scheme_type FROM schemes";
    $result = pg_query($conn,$sql);  //order executes
    if($result)
    {
        echo("query ran successfully");
        while($data = pg_fetch_row($result))
        {
            echo("<tr><td>$data[0]</td><td>$data[1]</td><td>$data[2]</td></tr>");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo("error in running query");
    }

?>

    </tbody>  
    </table>
    </div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <a href="#">#</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: shouldn;t this host=localhost port=5432 dbname=egram user=postgres password=password be host=localhost; port=5432; dbname=egram; user=postgres; password=password

Comment: i tried that....but its not working still and the video from which i wrote the code has not put ";" in between the entities either..